# How can I use static_files to create a link to a document with a dynamic name?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I have a file (a resume) which changes over time, also by name (say 'resume-january-2019.pdf', 'resume-march-2019.PDF', etc.

With Jekyll and Liquid, how can I use the static_files functionality to link to this document, without ever having  to change the link itself?

I find examples of looping over images, but since it is only one file, this is not what I want.

I have defined my static files in my _config.yml

```
defaults:
  - scope:
      path: "assets/files/resume"
    values:
      resume: true
```

I am looking for something like

```
<a href="{{ site.static_files.resume.path }}">Resume</a>
```

But then the href stays empty

I have also tried

```
{% assign resume = site.static_files | where: "resume", true %}
<p>Please read my <a href="{{ resume.path }}">Resume</a>.</p>
```

Here the href stays empty as well

I would expect it to be

```
<p>Please read my <a href="assets/files/resume/resume-january-2019.PDF">Resume</a>.</p>
```

And when I replace the resume with another file with another name, it to be

```
<p>Please read my <a href="assets/files/resume/resume-march-2019.pdf">Resume</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this by filtering the static files with a `where_exp`. You may need to add an additional `sort` filter based on the modified date value of the file, if you plan on having more than one resume file in that folder at a time. Example without the sorting:

```
{%- assign resume = site.static_files | where_exp: "file", "file.path contains 'files/resume'" -%}
<p>Please read my <a href="{{ resume[0].path }}">Resume</a>.</p>
```

The official Jekyll docs explain all the values you can access on a static file entry [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/static-files/) and the filters you can apply [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/).